# Fraud or just forgery

Tags: fraud

Gaming machine clearances at a licenced club require two employees to be present to count the monies from the machines. One employee only has done the clearance by himself ( employee A) then signed the official clearance document in his name and then falsely co-signed another persons signature (employee B) as if the other employee (B) was present at the clearance when he was not.
When questioned, employee (A) declared in writing that the second signature was indeed that of employee (B). Employee (B) has signed a stat. dec. that the second signature is not his.
Thus (A) has forged (B's) signature. Is this deliberate deceit fraud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a lawyer, but I expect that there are multiple count;

- forgery of signature
- violation of license (which i expect could be revoked for causes)

The club owner may also be negligent of not having sufficient procedures in place, so as a double key lockers, security cams, etc, so that they don't have to rely on people honesty and signatures alone.  Conflicting statements between person A and person B may come down to a examination of a signature expert.

Unless monies are missing, there may not be any fraud other than the signatory issues, but falsifying a signature does not automatically mean that the person have stolen anything.

Comment: If there has been money taken, the crime would be theft, not fraud.

Comment: Money taken = theft. Convinced someone through lies to hand over money = fraud.